# Hide time but display date in task bar

Tags: unity, indicator, clock

Is there a way to display only the date (ie, do *not* display the current time) in the indicators/tray area in Ubuntu with Unity?

In the settings panel at **System Settings > Time & Date > Clock**, there's an option to hide the date, but not the other way around.

The reason for this is that I find having the clock over there, staring at me, too distracting. On the other hand, I'd like to keep the indicator icon there, in order to have the clock handy when I need it (it's faster to click the icon than to type `date` in the Terminal).

I'd be willing to install other (3rd-party) indicator apps if the default one is not able to achieve this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the command line:

```
dconf write /com/canonical/indicator/datetime/time-format "'custom'"
dconf write /com/canonical/indicator/datetime/custom-time-format "'%a %d %h'"
```

For the datetime format, please refer to the [strftime()](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/man3/strftime.3.html) syntax.

To reset the settings:

```
dconf reset /com/canonical/indicator/datetime/time-format 
dconf reset /com/canonical/indicator/datetime/custom-time-format
```

Comment: I like the terminal way =) +1

Answer (score 5):

You can do this by using `dconf-tools`. So open a terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
```

Now, open dconf tools and go to com -> canonical -> indicator -> datetime

Change the value of `time-format` to `custom` and change the value of `custom-time-format` to `%F %A`. This will hide the time and display date as `YYYY-mm-dd <full weekday name>`.
 Refer to `man date` for other formats that you can use.

[image]

From `man date`:

```
%F     full date; same as %Y-%m-%d
%A     locale's full weekday name (e.g., Sunday)
```

Comment: and +1 for the GUI way =)

Comment: Thanks! I didn't try your way, since the command-line answer worked, but it's nice to have both options.